# $f''$ undefined but the second symmetric derivative exists?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

So far I have proved that,

> If $f''$ exists, then
>   $$f''(x) = \lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{f(x+h) + f(x-h) - 2f(x)}{h^2}}$$

But I have not managed to find an example where this limit exists and $f''$ does not. I tried something like $f(x) = x^{\frac{3}{2}}$ where $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ are both defined for $x = 0$ but $f''$ is not. But I am not even sure the given limit exists in this case.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ be any odd function discontinuous at 0, for instance
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
1,&x>0\\
0,&x=0\\
-1,&x<0.
\end{cases}
$$
Then the limit exists and is zero for $x=0$, but $f''$ does not exist at zero.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Let $g(h)=f(x+h)-f(x)$. Then, your limit is 
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(h)+g(-h)}{h^2}$$

If $g$ is an odd function, this limit is automatically $0$, but you can easily make this discontinuous at $h=0$.